# How to pass the selected value in dropdown in table to another page?

Tags: php, html

In this code, I have 2 dropdowns in the table (one is the options from MySQL and I checked the condition for options) and I want to pass their values for each row to the next page when I push the button "call" in that row.

So, how can I do this?

```
<table class="table-info">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>HN number</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>surname</th>
            <th>gender</th>
            <th>date of birth</th>
            <th>claim</th>
            <th>department</th>
            <th>unit</th>
            <th>tel</th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row["hn"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["first_name"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["last_name"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["gender"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["DOB"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["claim"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["dept"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["unit"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["tel"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["q_time"] ?></td>
            <td>
                <div action = "manage_db.php" method="post">

                    <select class="select" name="doc_drop" <?= ( $row["doc"] == 'general' ? '' : 'disabled' ) ?> require>
                        <option selected disabled>doctor</option>
                        <?php foreach($result2 as $doc_select){?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $doc_selectp["doc"];?>" 
                            <?= ( trim( $row["doc"] ) == $doc_select["doc"] ? 'selected' : '' ) ?> >                              
                                <?php echo $doc_select["doc"];?>
                            </option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>


                    <select  class="select" name="room" require>
                    <option  selected disabled> room </option>
                    <option value="1">room 1</option>
                    <option value="2">room 2</option>
                    <option value="3">room 3</option>
                    <option value="4">room 4</option>
                    <option value="5">room 5</option>
                
                     </select>

                     <a href="manage_db.php?hn_patient=<?php echo $row["hn"];?>" class = btn-call >call</a>
                    
                    </div>
        
                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsdUg.png)

Comment: you can pass the post value to $_SESSION and retrieve it anywhere you want

Comment: How about you start with an actual `form` - instead of adding nonsense attributes to a `div`? (`<div action = "manage_db.php" method="post">`) And then make that link into an actual submit button.